# Can this code be done with less media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

This seems very repetitive, is there a way that I can combine this so that I do not have to write `.more-photos a` and `@media` over and over again?

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199) {
  .more-photos a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .more-photos a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .more-photos a {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using viewport units that automatically scale as you resize the page?

Comment: Or a CSS preprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly simplified version (one less media query):

```
.more-photos a { font-size: 22px; }

@media (max-width: 1199px) { .more-photos a { font-size: 14px; } }

@media (max-width: 768px) { .more-photos a { font-size: 16px; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

No because that is how you write CSS rules and how they work. The only way to make your typing less might be to use a CSS pre-processor, such as SASS, which alleviates some typing but might not make your processed CSS look any different.